# Algorithmic error in java maze generator

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that generates 2-d mazes. The body of the maze is a 2-d int array. The border cells have a value of 2. Blocked cells (walls) have a value of 1, and empty cells (paths) have a value of 0. Initially, I am setting the value of all cells to 1. Then, starting from a random column in the top row, I move through the maze setting the current cell to 0 until I reach the bottom row.

This all worked fine, except that, rather than a single-line path, I often ended up with wide areas of 0's. So, I tried to add to the if statements to prevent it from marking cells zero if the cells around it were already zero. Unfortunately there is some flaw in my logic, causing the program to run forever without printing anything when I run it. Please help me identify that flaw.

I'm fairly new to programming, and am doing this as a learning exercise, so I'm also open to other algorithmic suggestions. Thanks

My code:

```
package RoboProj;

import java.util.Random;


public class Maze {
public int[][] grid;
final int width, height;

public Maze() {
    width = 20;
    height = 20;
    grid = new int[width][height];

    makeMaze();
}


public void makeMaze() {
    //* empty = 0, wall = 1, border = 2, travelled =3;

    //mark borders
    for (int curr = 0; curr < height; curr++) {
        grid[0][curr] = 2;  //top
        grid[curr][0]=2; //left
        grid[height -1][curr] = 2; //bottom
        grid[curr][width-1] = 2; //right
    }
    //initially mark all cells as walls
    for (int row = 1; row < height-1; row++){
        for (int col = 1; col < width-1; col++){
            grid[row][col]=1;
        }      
    }

    int row = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    int col =  r.nextInt(width);

    grid[row][col] = 0;

    while (row != height-1){
        int next = r.nextInt(4);
        if (next == 0 && row-1 > 0 && grid[row-1][col-1] == 1 && grid[row-1][col+1] == 1){
            grid[row-1][col]=0;
            row = row-1;
          //  System.out.print(next);
        }
        if (next == 1 && grid[row+1][col-1] == 1 && grid[row+1][col+1] == 1){
            grid[row+1][col]=0;
            row = row+1;
           // System.out.print(next);
        }      
        if (next == 2&& col-1 > 0 && grid[row+1][col-1] == 1 && grid[row-1][col-1] == 1){
            grid[row][col-1]=0;
            col = col-1;
                  //     System.out.print(next);
        } 
        if (next == 3 && col+1 < width-1 && grid[row-1][col+1] == 1 && grid[row+1][col+1] == 1){
            grid[row][col+1]=0;
            col = col+1;
                   //     System.out.print(next);
        } 
    }
}
}
```

@ Anupam Saini: I'm looking for something like this, where the "pathway" is never more than one cell wide.

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Are you allowing for the square you came from to be `0`?  It could be causing an infinite loop.  Also, if the program can decide to move up, it is possible for it to trap itself.

Comment: Can you paste the correct output in terms of maze, it will give me a clear idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you go back on the path if you are blocked (think about the case you generate a U shape ending back on the upper row and there is no way to go down without intersecting the existing path) or if the random generator generates a step to a cell that is already marked with 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit to make it more readable. I am using switch case statement to indicate movement in the maze, 0 denotes left turn i denotes right turn and 2 denotes down movement. The

> isValidTurn()

and

> moveMouse()

are the methods of interest.

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Maze {
    private final int[][] grid;
    private final int width, height;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Maze mz = new Maze(20, 20);
        mz.moveMouse();
    }

    private void generateDefaultMaze() {
        System.out.println(this);
        // * empty = 0, wall = 1, border = 2, travelled =3;

        // mark borders
        for (int curr = 0; curr < height; curr++) {
            grid[0][curr] = 2; // top
            grid[curr][0] = 2; // left
            grid[height - 1][curr] = 2; // bottom
            grid[curr][width - 1] = 2; // right
        }
        // initially mark all cells as walls
        for (int row = 1; row < height - 1; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col < width - 1; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public Maze(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        grid = new int[width][height];
        this.generateDefaultMaze();
    }

    /**
     * Overridden method to generate a human readable maze state.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
                sb.append(this.grid[i][j]).append(",");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("**************");
        sb.append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Row pointer can either move left or right and it's value should be
     * between 0 and width. In case of 0 value at this grid[row][col] do not
     * move the pointer.
     * 
     * @param row The row pointer value.
     * @param col The column pointer value.
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isValidTurn(int row, int col) {
        if (row >= 0 && row < width && !(this.grid[col][row] == 0)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void moveMouse() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int row = r.nextInt(width);
        int col = 0;

        grid[col][row] = 0;
        // System.out.println(this);
        while (col < (this.height - 1)) {
            // Assuming the mouse moves in only 3 directions left right or down
            // in the maze. 0 indicates left turn 1 indicates right turn and
            // 2 indicates down movement in the maze.
            int nextDir = r.nextInt(3);
            switch (nextDir) {
            case 0: // left turn
                if (this.isValidTurn((row - 1), col)) {
                    --row;
                    this.grid[col][row] = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 1: // right turn
                if (this.isValidTurn((row + 1), col)) {
                    ++row;
                    this.grid[col][row] = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2: // down movement
                ++col;
                this.grid[col][row] = 0;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("turn : " + nextDir);
            // System.out.println(this);
        }
        System.out.println(this);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks so much. It's a really nice piece of code. For educational purposes, could you please help me understand exactly what isValidTurn() checks for. Why do you need to call this, rather than just calling grid[col][row]. I'm still trying to wrap my head around everything the this statement can do.

Comment: In a row you can only move left or right, isValidTurn checks if the next movement is within 0 and width of the grid, otherwise you will end up with indexOutOfBound exception and it also checks the value at that location in grid, if it is 0 then no point in moving.   Please ignore the this statement :) , but note the System.out.println(this); statement calls the toString() method of the Maze class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: And it does so because the method in which the this statement is called is in the maze class, correct? So, if I called System.out.println(this) in any other method of the maze class, it would likewise print the maze. And if I called it in a method (or constructor?) of the Foo class, it would print the Foo object according to its toString() method. Right?

Comment: Yes you are correct :) , Please keep in mind when you do System.out.println(this), the println method is actually calling this.toString() method. In case your Foo class does not override toString method the toString of Object class will be invoked which will print the hashcode of the Foo class instance (default toString implementation)